# Alamofire huge file upload request with multipart/form-data takes very long to respond

Tags: ios, swift, upload, alamofire, multipartform-data

I'm using Alamofire with multipart/form-data and InputStream for my upload request. It works very well for files below 100MB, but after 100MB, request takes very long time to respond. Am I doing something wrong with my code? 
Here's my request:

```
    let parameters: [String: String] = // my necessary parameters here
    let stream = InputStream(url: fileURL)

    AlamofireConstants.sessionManager.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

          for (key, value) in parameters {
             multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
          }

          multipartFormData.append(stream!,
                                withLength: UInt64(fileSize),
                                name: "file",
                                fileName: fileName,
                                mimeType: GetMimeType(ext: fileExtension))

    },  usingThreshold: SessionManager.multipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
        to: linkToUpload,
        method: .post,
        headers: ["Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"],
        encodingCompletion: { result in
                ... // handling success & failure here
   })
```

Comment: did you try to repeat your flow with Postman? is there the same behavior (long response time)? I'd recommend to discuss this behavior with backend developers (or who server supports)

Comment: Most likely the server has a 100MB upload limit (a typical value) and isn't returning an error in a timely manner.

Comment: Server does not have a upload limit, upload operation is working successfully, but it takes very long to respond for big files.